# insert new record from TFDquery into another sqlite db (firemonkey)

Tags: sqlite, firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have 2 SQLite databases.  I want to take several records from one and insert them into the other.  What is a good way of doing this?  I'm showing question marks below where I'm not sure what I need...

```
TFDQuery *queryNEWDATA;
queryNEWDATA = new TFDQuery(NULL);
queryNEWDATA->Connection = Form1->FDConnection1;   
queryNEWDATA->SQL->Text = "SELECT * FROM mtgs WHERE status = 4";  
queryNEWDATA->Open();
while(!queryNEWDATA->Eof) 
{
  TFDQuery *queryUPDATE;
  queryUPDATE = new TFDQuery(NULL);
  queryUPDATE->Connection = Form1->FDConnection2; 

  queryUPDATE->SQL->Text = ????????????????

  queryUPDATE->ExecSQL();
  queryUPDATE->Close();
  queryUPDATE->DisposeOf();
}
```

If my `queryNEWDATA` returns 4 records, I want to just push them into the other database with `queryUPDATE`.  Note that both databases have the exact same structure and column order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the *best* way, but try something like this:

```
TFDQuery *queryNEWDATA = new TFDQuery(NULL);
queryNEWDATA->Connection = Form1->FDConnection1;   
queryNEWDATA->SQL->Text = _D("SELECT * FROM mtgs WHERE status = 4");
queryNEWDATA->Open();

if (!queryNEWDATA->Eof) 
{
    TStringList *FieldNames = new TStringList;
    TStringList *ParamNames = new TStringList;

    int FieldCount = queryNEWDATA->Fields->Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < FieldCount; ++i)
    {
        String FieldName = queryNEWDATA->Fields->Fields[i]->FieldName;
        FieldNames->Add(FieldName);
        ParamNames->Add(_D(":P") + FieldName);
    }

    TFDQuery *queryUPDATE = new TFDQuery(NULL);
    queryUPDATE->Connection = Form1->FDConnection2;     
    queryUPDATE->SQL->Text = _D("INSERT INTO mtgs (") + FieldNames->CommaText + _D(") VALUES (") + ParamNames->CommaText + _D(")");

    FieldNames->DisposeOf();
    ParamNames->DisposeOf();

    for (int i = 0; i < FieldCount; ++i)
    {
        TField *f = queryNEWDATA->Fields->Fields[i];
        queryUPDATE->Params->ParamByName(_D("P") + f->FieldName)->DataType = f->DataType;
    }

    queryUPDATE->Prepare();

    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < FieldCount; ++i)
        {
            TField *f = queryNEWDATA->Fields->Fields[i];
            queryUPDATE->Params->ParamByName(_D("P") + f->FieldName)->Value = f->Value;
        }

        queryUPDATE->ExecSQL();
        queryNEWDATA->Next();
    }
    while (!queryNEWDATA->Eof);

    queryUPDATE->Close();
    queryUPDATE->DisposeOf();
}

queryNEWDATA->Close();
queryNEWDATA->DisposeOf();
```

Comment: Thanks Remy.  I think there is an extra comma getting in somewhere.  I added logging and found that the code fails at queryUPDATE->Prepare().  The queryUPDATE->SQL->Text right before the fail is INSERT INTO mtgs (,,,,,,,) VALUES (:P,:P,:P,:P,:P,:P,:P,:P,)

Comment: The exception message I'm getting is [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR near ",": syntax error

Comment: @relayman357 the syntax error is complaining about the 1st `,` after the opening `(`. The SQL text you showed means `Fields[i]->Name` is returning a blank string when it shouldn't be. And if the `CommaText` is outputting a trailing comma after the last string, that is an RTL bug. The SQL should look more like this: `INSERT INTO mtgs (Field1,Field2,Field3,...) VALUES (:PField1,:PField2,:PField3,...)`, where `Field#` is an actual field name, like `status`, etc

Comment: FieldCount logs as 8, which is correct.  I dumped one of the fields to log using queryNEWDATA->FieldByName("title")->AsString and it shows the correct data for that field from a record in the db.

Comment: Remy, I changed 1 line of your code to String FieldName =  queryNEWDATA->Fields->Fields[i]->FieldName and I get a new error. New error is:  "[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite]-335.  Parameter [PPOS] data type is unknown.   Hint:  specify TFDParam.DataType or assign TFDParam value before Prepare/Execute call."     Note that the first field in my table is named POS.

Comment: Also, when I log the text of the string FieldName after using that 1 line of modified code above (where I replaced Name with FieldName) all of the field names show up properly in the log.  This new error (-335) above must be unrelated.

Comment: Remy - that works perfectly.  Thank you for your time and help.